# Sending images over http to browser in C

Tags: c, http, image-processing, server

A am new to C and I am trying to implement a web server in C. I can successfully send .txt and .html files to the browser. However, I can't send any images, although I have correct content-type header which recognises that the image is .jpg. 
Here is the function I use to find the content-type:

```
char *find_content_type (char *filename) {
    char *p;  // pointer to the type found
    int i;
    char buf1[MAXFILENAME]; // used to store the extension of the file
    char buf2[MAXFILENAME];

    p = (char *)malloc(30);
    strcpy(buf1, filename);
    printf("name of file requested: %s \n", buf1);

    /* find the extension: */
    for (i = 0; i<strlen(buf1); i++) {
        if ( buf1[i] == '.' ) {
            strcpy(buf2, &buf1[i]);
        }
    }
    /* find the type: */
    if ( strcmp(buf2, ".html") == 0 || strcmp (buf2, ".hml") == 0) {
        strcpy (buf2, "Content-Type: text/html \r\n");
    }

    else if ( strcmp(buf2, ".txt") == 0) {
        strcpy (buf2, "Content-Type: text/plain \r\n");
    }

    else if ( strcmp(buf2, ".jpg") == 0 || strcmp (buf2, ".jpeg") == 0) {
        strcpy (buf2, "Content-Type: image/jpeg \r\n");
    }

    else if ( strcmp(buf2, ".gif") == 0) {
        strcpy (buf2, "Content-Type: image/gif \r\n");
    }

    else {
        strcpy (buf2, "Content-Type: application/octet-stream \r\n");
    }

     p = buf2;
    printf ("content-type: %s\n", p);
    //return "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n";
    return p;
}
```

I have function which parses the request and returns a pointer to the name of the file requested. In main I only accept requests and write to the browser, all data parsing and response constructing is outside main. The function below forms the response which will be sent to the browser:

```
char * response_generator (char *filename) {
    char *p; // pointer to the whole response
    char *content_type; // pointer to the content type
    char data [MAXLEN], data2[MAXLEN - 100], data3 [MAXLEN - 200];
    /* vars needed for finding the length of the file */
    struct stat filestat;
    FILE *fp;
    int fd;
    off_t size;
    char filesize[6], name[30]; 

    strcpy (name, filename);
    if ( ((fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY)) < -1) || (fstat(fd, &filestat) < 0) ) {
        printf ("Error in measuring the size of the file");
    }
    if (filename == NULL) {
        // I have measured the length of my 400.html file
        strcpy (data, "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 327\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("400index.html", "r");
    }
    sprintf (filesize, "%d", filestat.st_size); // put the file size of buffer, so we can add it to the response header

    fp = fopen (name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL || strcmp (name,"404") == 0 ) {
         // I have measured the length of my 404.html file
         strcpy (data, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 165\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("404index.html", "r");
    }
    else if (fp != NULL) {
        strcpy (data, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
        /* content-length: */
        strcat (data, filesize);
        strcat (data, "\r\n");
        /* content-type: */
        strcpy (data2, find_content_type (name));
        printf ("content-type: %s\n", find_content_type (name));
        strcat (data, data2);
    }

    else {
        // I have measured the length of my 500.html file
        strcpy (data, "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nContent-Length: 190\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("500index.html", "r");
    }      

    strcat (data, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
    fread (data3, sizeof(char), filestat.st_size + 150, fp); /* read the file in a data buffer: */
    strcat (data, data3);
    data[strlen(data)] = '\0';
    p = data;
    fclose(fp);
    return p;
}
```

It is pretty long and heavy function, but it seems to work fine apart when I have to send images, as I mentioned. When I print the request to be send on the terminal what I get is:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Length: 49657
 Content-Type: image/jpeg 
 Connection: keep-alive

 ÿØÿà
```

If you have any idea, please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Comment: TLDR: binary data has embedded `'\0'`s. String functions (`str*()`) aren't meant to deal with binary data.

Comment: Have a look at the file in a hex-editor. Take particular note of the first 5 bytes. Now look at the two lines that follow the "Connection: keep-alive" field of the header. See the problem yet?

Comment: So I shouldn't add '\0' at the end of data?

Comment: Do response_generator returns a pointer to a local variable ? Will not end well...

Comment: @Iva - No, you shouldn't be using strcat to move data that includes NULLs. Binary data includes NULLs, so you have to copy your data in a different way. You also have to give the response_generator function a means by which it can return the length of the output, since you have to use functions to move this data that includes NULLs which are unable to infer its length - like the str* functions do.

Comment: Yes. response_generator returns pointer to the data that will be writen to the browser in main.

Comment: @Iva - You should never ever return a pointer to a local variable. Local variables sit on stack memory, and should not be used after the function they're declared in returns.

Comment: Although you *can* build the response in memory and then push the whole thing to the client, it is more usual to stream (most of) the data directly to the client as you go, without first building the whole response.  That will be especially true for binary data, such as images, because (1) the responses can be very large, and (2) you cannot use string I/O functions for binary data any more successfully than you can use string manipulation functions for such data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, will it be better if I directly sent a header response to the server directly, just after it is ready without storing it and building a big buffer, as I do?

Comment: @Iva, I would recommend doing that, yes, but that in itself will not resolve the problem you asked about.

Comment: Ok, so my problem, as I understand, is that in response_generator after all str* functions I use, I actually change the contains of the file. So, I must avoid using those functions when manipulating the file contents. A possible solution I see is to directly write to the browser whatever I have read from the file. So, after the line "fread (data3, sizeof(char), filestat.st_size + 150, fp);" I directly make "write (conn_fd, data3, strlen (data3));" ? Is that right?

Comment: NO, `strlen` cannot be used to measure the length of a binary buffer. Use  `filestat.st_size` or the return value from `fread`.

Comment: As others have commented, if you are not dealing with null-terminated character arrays, you MUST stop using the str* calls.  strlen() is NOT magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it. There were multiple problems. First, I removed all (str*()), because, as mentioned on the comments, they ARE NOT meant to deal with binary data. I removed the unnecessary number of buffers. Now I have two: the first one is for storing the response headers, it is safe to use strcat/strcpy, etc on it. I write to the browser the header response as soon as I have them. The second buffer contains the data of the file that the browser requested. I write it to the server immediately after I have read it from the file, so I avoid any manipulations that might cause problems. Here is my code for the response_generator:

```
void response_generator (int conn_fd, char *filename) {

    /* vars needed for finding the length of the file */
    struct stat filestat;
    FILE *fp;
    int fd;
    char header_buff [HEADER_LEN];
    char file_buff [MAXLEN];
    char filesize[7];//, name[30]; 

    if ( ((fd = open (filename, O_RDONLY)) < -1) || (fstat(fd, &filestat) < 0) ) {
        printf ("Error in measuring the size of the file");
}

    if (filename == NULL) {
        // I have measured the length of my 400.html file
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Length: 327\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("400index.html", "r");
    }

    sprintf (filesize, "%zd", filestat.st_size); // put the file size of buffer, so we can add it to the response header
    fp = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    printf ("fp is null or filename = 404\n");
        // I have measured the length of my 404.html file
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 165\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("404index.html", "r");
    }

    else if (fp != NULL) {
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
        /* content-length: */
        strcat (header_buff, filesize);
        strcat (header_buff, "\r\n");
        /* content-type: */
        strcat (header_buff, find_content_type (filename));
        printf ("%s\n", find_content_type (filename));
    }

    else {
        // I have measured the length of my 500.html file
        strcpy (header_buff, "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\nContent-Length: 190\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n");
        fp = fopen ("500index.html", "r");
    }        

    strcat (header_buff, "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
    write (conn_fd, header_buff, strlen(header_buff));

    fread (file_buff, sizeof(char), filestat.st_size + 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    write (conn_fd, file_buff, filestat.st_size);

    close (conn_fd);
}
```

Thanks very much for the comments on my problem, they really helped me in fixing this piece of code.